# React Native Modal closes on multitouch (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog

<s>I am developing a React Native app, and I am using the Modal component provided by React Native. The problem is that, on Android, all my modals close themselves when I move 2 fingers on them.</s>

For example, if I put a map on a modal and I try to pinch it, the modal closes.

But even for a very simple blank modal, if I move 2 fingers on it, it closes.

This problem is occuring on another React Native app as well. I didn't find any occurence of this question on the web.

How can we do to allow multitouch on a React Native modal?

**[edit] Sorry, the problem came from my specific implemention of Modals and the problem described above doesn't exist in general.**

Comment: hey @Arnaud what was the problem after all? I'm having the same issue but I can't find asolution

Comment: @Arnaud please provide what was causing the issue, so that others may learn how to implement modal correctly. I'm having the same issue

Comment: Yeah, third person here who's having the same thing. You fixed it for yourself but won't share..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  `<View pointerEvents="box-none" />` for the `modal container`

There are more props you can use for the views
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents

try changing them based on your component tree